# How to configure HAProxy to consolidate outbound appserver connections

Tags: web-applications, networking, haproxy

I would like to use my HAProxy server to consolidate out bound application server requests. My application interacts with 3rd party, external services and I would like to be able to interact with these services using a single IP address. I would also like to be able to do this via HTTP and HTTPS. Any examples on the configuration to do this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use exactly the same setup as you have in front of your web servers, with the IP of your 3rd party in the "server" statement(s). Many people do that to reach third party and enforce a timeout on connection and requests. It also allows you to monitor the service a little bit, an get availability stats.